# Excel vba selection.copy from hidden workbook app doesn't work

Tags: vba, excel

I have a main workbook that contains the macros and a hidden workbook that contains data which is opened like this:

```
Dim ExcelApp As Object
Set ExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
ExcelApp.Visible = False
ExcelApp.ScreenUpdating =  False
ExcelApp.DisplayAlerts = False
ExcelApp.EnableEvents = False
Dim creditsWorkbook As Workbook
Set creditsWorkbook = ExcelApp.Application.Workbooks.Open("P:\2017\" & DATA & ".xlsx")
```

Later in code I select a range in that data workbook and copy it, and paste it into the main workbook:

```
creditsWorkbook.Worksheets("List1").Range(creditsWorkbook.Worksheets("List1").Cells(5, 1), creditsWorkbook.Worksheets("List1").Cells(lastStr3, lastStb3)).Select
creditsWorkbook.Worksheets("List1").Activate
'creditsWorkbook.Worksheets("List1").Selection.Copy   '<--- error
Selection.Copy  <--- works, but copies from the Main workbook wrong stuff
Windows("Main.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("Credit portfolio").Select
Range("a4").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

`lastStr3` and `lastStb3` are just integers that contain the number of rows and columns to select from `creditsWorkbook`. The selection works fine (I can see it when turning on visibility), but the copy method gets messed.

I tried activating `creditWorkbook` first, tried to specify what to copy like this `creditsWorkbook.Worksheets("List1").Selection.Copy`, but it just gives an error `object doesn't support this property or method`. I'm not sure what should I do to get the needed results.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why select > activate > copy. Change your first select to copy `creditsWorkbook.Worksheets("List1").Range(creditsWorkbook.Worksheets("List1").Cells(5, 1), creditsWorkbook.Worksheets("List1").Cells(lastStr3, lastStb3)).Copy`

Comment: @Tim Wilkinson, I changed that to copy as you suggested, but I get now an error when pasting: `Pastespecial method of range class failed`. Not sure why. If it copied the range, what's the matter with pasting it?

Answer (score 1):

Avoid using `Select` where possible.

```
With creditsWorkbook.Worksheets("List1")
    .Range(.Cells(5, 1), .Cells(lastStr3, lastStb3)).Copy
End With
Windows("Main.xlsm").Sheets("Credit portfolio").Range("A4").PasteSpecial_ 
    Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

Comment: It gives an error on this line: `Windows("Main.xlsm").Sheets("Credit portfolio").Range("A4").PasteSpecial_ 
    Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False`: `Object doesn't support this property or method`.

Comment: Rather than `Windows("Main.xlsm").Sheets("Credit portfolio")...` try `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Credit portfolio").Range...`. That's presuming that your macro is in **Main.xlsm**

Comment: I've just tried and that worked for me. Can you try copying something from your active workbook using the same method

Comment: @Zac, I made the hidden app visible and tried to the copy pasting manually. What I figured is when I open the Main workbook and try to paste in A4 cell there appears an message that the range I attempt to paste has formulas that are going to be pasted as values. And that perhaps there was an attempt of pasting formulas from a proteceted mode or another Excel app. It looks like my case is I try to paste from one excel app to another, that's why that message appears. When I click ok it works, but I wonder why you didn't get the message and how to get rid of it n code.

Comment: Try adding this before you attempt to copy: `Application.DisplayAlerts = False`. Remember to set it back to `True` after the copy